# how to Retrieve data from prepopSQLite DB

Tags: android

i have created one prepop SQLite database in that i have stored three columns _id, name and lname. so i am unable to retrieve data from the database.

PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java

```
public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String DB_NAME = "test";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
private static final String FRIEND_ID = "_id";
private static final String FRIEND_NAME = "name";
private static final String FRIEND_LNAME = "lname";

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> friends;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this,
            DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    fillFreinds();
    setUpList();
}

private void setUpList() {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friends));
    listView = getListView();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void fillFreinds() {
    friends = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_LNAME }, null, null, null, null,
            FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_LNAME);

    friendCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            String name = friendCursor.getString(1);
            String lname = friendCursor.getString(2);
            friends.add(name);
            friends.add(lname);
        } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    friendCursor.close();
}
```

}

Error is= illegalArgumentException: Invalid LIMIT clauses: lname

Comment: somebody please help me. m frustrate :-(

Answer (score 0):

Last column value should be integer.
Please change it from FRIEND_LNAME  to desired integer value.

```
Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
        FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_LNAME }, null, null, null, null,
        FRIEND_NAME, "5");
```

Comment: Then it will gives this error..08-29 12:23:07.027: E/SQLiteLog(1519): (1) no such column: lname
08-29 12:23:07.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 12:23:07.107: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softeq.android.prepopdb/com.softeq.prepopdb.PrepopSqliteDbActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: lname (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, lname FROM friends ORDER BY name LIMIT 5

Comment: have you added the FRIEND_LNAME now and it was not present before? if yes then uninstall the application from device before installig it again, it will solve your problem

Comment: logcat= java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT _id, name, lname FROM friends)